Efficient function writing in Excel

I have a dataset with about 10.000 rows and 4 columns worth of discharge data. I have a set of row numbers I'm interested in (top row in the picture) and need to find the maximum value in those row numbers from column C and the sum of the values in those rows in column D.
Is there a way where i don't have to manually write the function every time but Excel can do it for me based on the row numbers in the top?
I have written out the functions manually so far, but this is not feasible for larger datasets.

What do you mean by need to find the maximum value in those row numbers from column C?

Which version of Excel do you have? If you have 365: =MAX(INDEX(C:C,TEXTBEFORE(G1,"-")+0):INDEX(C:C,TEXTAFTER(G1,"-")+0)) for example.

@Harun24hr I mean the maximum value in the row numbers as specified in row 1, so the maximum value in C271-C273, the maximum value in C343-346, etc.

If you have M365:
=MAX(INDEX(C:C,TEXTBEFORE(G1,"-")+0):INDEX(C:C,TEXTAFTER(G1,"-")+0))

for example

And if they don't have M365, just use LEFT/MID and FIND instead of TEXTBEFORE/TEXTAFTER: =MAX(INDEX(C:C,--LEFT(G1,FIND("-",G1)-1)):INDEX(C:C,--MID(G1,FIND("-",G1)+1,99)))

Nice addition @Chronocidal I don't believe the -- is required inside INDEX, since that converts numbers stored as text to their numbervalue. For example try =INDEX(A:A,"3")

'Spill'ing future entries (requires Microsoft 365):
=LET(
    separator, "-",
    max_col, C:C,
    sum_col, D:D,
    row_numbers_with_future_entries, TAKE($1:$1, , 50),
    row_numbers, FILTER(
        row_numbers_with_future_entries,
        ISNUMBER(FIND(separator, row_numbers_with_future_entries))
    ),
    REDUCE(
        VSTACK("Max in C", "Sum from D"),
        row_numbers,
        LAMBDA(acc, start_end,
            LET(
                split, TEXTSPLIT(start_end, separator),
                start, INDEX(split, 1, 1),
                end, INDEX(split, 1, 2),
                HSTACK(
                    acc,
                    VSTACK(
                        MAX(INDEX(max_col, start):INDEX(max_col, end)),
                        SUM(INDEX(sum_col, start):INDEX(sum_col, end))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)


